# Taking inner subset result of one join and combining this with an outer join

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables that I would like to join, df1, df2 and df3. I would like to take the results from df1/df2 and then join this to df3.

I would like to join tables df1 and df2 ON version and name with the conditions of the purpose
= 'hi' or 'cat'
I would then like to take the result of this subset and apply it to my outer join of df1
df1 would join this inner table on host and pc

df1

```
version host    date                                      
pat     a16     12/1/2019   
fam     a16     12/1/2019   
emp     a16     12/1/2019   
dan     a16     12/1/2019
```

df2

```
name    purpose
pat     hi
fam     cat
emp     dog
dan     bird
```

df3

```
pc  size    free  date
a16 5       1     12/1/2019
a40 4       3     12/1/2019
a41 3       1     12/1/2019
```

**DESIRED**

```
version host    date          name    purpose   pc   size    free  date
pat     a16     12/1/2019     pat     hi        a16  5       1     12/1/2019
fam     a16     12/1/2019     fam     cat
```

**DOING**

```
SELECT   SUM(df3.size) AS size, SUM(df.3.free) AS free,
         df3.date
FROM     df3
               (SELECT DISTINCT 
                       df2.purpose, df2.name,
                       df1.version, df1.host
               FROM    df1
               JOIN    df2  ON 
                       df2.name = df1.version
               WHERE   df2.purpose = 'cat' OR df2.purpose = 'hi')
               AS NEW
JOIN     df3 ON 
df3.pc = NEW.host
```

However, my values are double, as there appear to be duplicates. I am still researching. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few errors in your code but those may have been typos so I did not directly point those out and just fixed them (because they appeared to be typos).

You also duplicated the df3 in your join where not needed that is most likely causing your duplicates.  The below should work.

```
SELECT   SUM(df3.size) AS size, SUM(df3.free) AS free, df3.date
FROM     df3
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT df2.purpose, df2.name, df1.version, df1.host
    FROM    df1
    JOIN    df2  ON df2.name = df1.version
    WHERE   df2.purpose = 'cat' OR df2.purpose = 'hi'
) AS NEW ON df3.pc = NEW.host
Group by df3.date
```

Comment: No GROUP BY needed?

Comment: @jarlh  You are correct I added the Group By

Answer (score 1):

You can inner join with df1 and df2 first. Then use that resulting table to join with df3.

```
select *
from df3 join 
  (
   select *
   from df1 join df2 on df1.version = df2.name
  ) df12
on df3.pc = df12.host
where df12.purpose = "hi" or df12.purpose = "cat";
```

To explain further, the inner sub-query is:

```
select *
from df1 join df2 on df1.version = df2.name


| version | host | date_of_purchase | name | purpose |
|---------|------|------------------|------|---------|
|     pat |  a16 |       2021-01-20 |  pat |      hi |
|     fam |  a16 |       2021-01-20 |  fam |     cat |
|     emp |  a16 |       2021-01-20 |  emp |     dog |
|     dan |  a16 |       2021-01-20 |  dan |    bird |
```

Then the outer query results in

```
|  pc | size | free | date_of_purchase | version | host | date_of_purchase | name | purpose |
|-----|------|------|------------------|---------|------|------------------|------|---------|
| a16 |    5 |    1 |       2021-01-20 |     pat |  a16 |       2021-01-20 |  pat |      hi |
| a16 |    5 |    1 |       2021-01-20 |     fam |  a16 |       2021-01-20 |  fam |     cat |
```

Here's a fiddle for all the above (including created tables with your provided inputs): http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/32457b/19